# Rearrange Images in PPTX Power Point slide using OpenXML and C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

Using open xml to open pptx file i need to programatically rearange images to reflect an array.

Having trouble getting images using

```
slide.Descendants DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture()
```

always null

i have 4 images and title in one slide and i need to programatically change order in which they appear

pptx is loaded from a SQL Server  binary stream

any help would be appreciatted thank you

**EDIT :**

This is the code snippet :

```
foreach (var item in slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()); 
{ 
    string id = item.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Id; 
    string desc = item.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Description; 
}
```

Comment: Please show the code with what you have tried so far and what isn't working as you expect.  This is a very broad question as it stands.

Comment: foreach (var item in  slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>());
                    {

                        
                        string id = item.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Id;
                        string desc = item.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Description;

                        
                        
                    }